# Why .change works only when I select an element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qTCNe/) code :

```
Yes <input type="radio" value="txt1" name="myRadio" id="text1" checked=true />
No <input type="radio" value="txt2" name="myRadio" id="text2" />

$('#text1').change(function() {
    alert('changed');
    return;
});
```

that handler only the id=text1 (yeah, I should do this on the name). But it should works anyway. In fact it works only when I select the checkbox text1, not when I select text2.

Why? And how can I fix this?

Comment: -1... mah... I can't believe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the inputs in a div. Right now, you're only referencing the first input.

```
<div id="container">
Yes <input type="radio" value="txt1" name="myRadio" id="text1" checked=true />
No <input type="radio" value="txt2" name="myRadio" id="text2" />
</div>

$('#container input').click(function() {
    alert('changed');
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this works only on text1 cause your event is attached only to the element with the id = text1. How else do u want it to work. Yes you have to use the name "myRadio" to make it work on both.

Comment: Yeah ouf course, but text1 change when i select it and when I leave from it... it make more logic for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer given to wrap it in a div changes the page layout.  If you need to do this without affecting the page then you can select the radio element by name:

```
$('input[name="myRadio"]').change(function() {
    alert('changed');
    return;
});
```